# Backordering a domain with its current registrar?

Tags: domains, godaddy

I'm eyeing a domain which is currently registered with godaddy, and the owner seems inactive and unlikely to renew the domain. I have already subscribed to a backordering service, but as this is a domain I'd really like to get, I'm wondering that if I use GoDaddy's backordering service will GoDaddy get preferential treatment (i.e. be able to prevent it going to the general market)

Answer (score 1):

> [SOURCE](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-are-domain-backorders-597)
>
> For Domain Names Expiring at GoDaddy®
>
> You backorder a domain name — You can purchase a backorder for a domain name before it expires. There is no limit on the number of GoDaddy customers who can backorder a domain name. For instructions on placing a backorder, see Setting up Domain Backorders.
>
> You monitor the domain name — With your free Domain Monitoring membership, you can monitor your backordered domain name and receive email notifications within 24 hours of any changes in registrar, status, expiration date, or nameservers.
>
> When the backorder reaches its available date, the registry will release the domain name to the public. At this time, we will attempt to acquire domain names via backorder. The domain's "available state" status does not guarantee the domain name will be captured.

You will not get preferential treatment even if the domain is registrar at GoDaddy, its not a guaranteed service. The domain could even enter auction regardless of you backorder.

It can also be scooped up by other companies that may hammer the registration the moment its dropped.(roughly 3months after its expired, and normally within a 3-12hour window, there are companies that you can pay to snatch it the moment its released, it costs alot of this service and its an auction). A expired domain does not drop for 90 days on most TLD and CCTLDs.